# How do I use a preprocess function for a node template?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to preprocess my variable array in drupal 8, But it's not working well.I'm checked with the Bartik theme also, But getting the same error here. When I'm trying to print the variable array its giving a blank page result. How can I preprocess my variable array for a node template?

```
`function bartik_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Remove the "Add new comment" link on teasers or when the comment form is
  // displayed on the page.
  if ($variables['teaser'] || !empty($variables['content']['comments']['comment_form'])) {
    unset($variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);
  }
  print_r($variables);
}`
```

This is the function I'm tried to checkout the issue in bartik theme.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using `print_r()` enable devel module and their new submodule called kint. And use `kint()` instead of `print_r()`. You can also use `print_r()` but is messy.

> How can I preprocess my variable array for a node template?

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  kint($variables);
}
```

If this does not work it might be a cache problem.  I will recommend you to set you website into dev mode using DrupalConsole. `drupal site:mode dev`

Why ?

> The Twig engine provides options for configuring debugging, automatic
>   reloading (recompiling) of templates, and caching compiled templates
>   in the filesystem. By default, the Twig theming engine compiles
>   templates into PHP code and stores the compiled code in memory.
>   Compiled code is unsuitable for development, since changes in Twig
>   templates are not immediately updated in your Drupal site. Twig cache
>   can be cleared through Drupal's clear cache interface, but for ongoing
>   development it's easier to change Drupal's settings so that Twig
>   doesn't cache anything at all.

Running  `drupal site:mode dev` will disable all twig cache. For more information about debugging please visit - [Debugging compiled Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374)

Comment: Thanks for your kind information. Could you please tell me how can i enable these modules in drupal 8. Actually I'm new to the Drupal world.

Comment: [Installing contributed modules (Drupal 8)](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes/modules-8)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the [VarDumper module](https://www.drupal.org/project/vardumper) which isn't quite so memory intensive as Kint. I find it a bit more user-friendly and better-looking!

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  vardumper($variables);
}
```

[image: Drupal VarDumper example]